# Scroll Height increases when I type in text area

Tags: jquery

I have a text area that I am resizing automatically if needed. I have it working but i see a small issue that I dont understand.

When on my element I call on keyup. In there I set the scroll height to be whatever the text area is. So when a user hits enter it will grow. My issue is that the first time when a user enters the text area and start typing the box extends a small bit. But I dont understand how the scroll height could have changed. Can anyone explain to me why that is happening? If you run the code you will see the text jumping each time you hit enter, dont worry about that. Cheers
Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
}

.Conor{
min-height: 20px; /* for default height */
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
```

}

```
<body>

<div class='containter' >
<div>
    fghfghg
</div>
<textarea class='textArea' rows = 2 style='width: 60%'>

</textarea>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">          
      <textarea class='taClass' rows = 2 style='width: 100%'></textarea>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<div>
<textarea> this is a test</textarea>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```
$('.textArea').trigger('click');
var position = null;
$('.containter').on('click', '.textArea', function(){
           console.log($(this).position());
            console.log($(this).parent().attr('class'));
            position = $(this).position();
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            $('.modal').css({top: position.top, left: position.left, width: $(this).width(), height: $(this).height()});
            $('.modal').show();
            $('.taClass').height(this.scrollHeight);
            $('.taClass').focus();
    });

$('.taClass').on('keyup',function(e){
    $(this).css('height','auto');
    $(this).height(this.scrollHeight);
});

$(document).click(function(event){
        if (event.target.className != 'textArea' && event.target.className != 'taClass') {
            $('.modal').hide();
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the `line-height` is slightly larger than the 20px `min-height` you've defined. Have you tried changing your `line-height` or making the `min-height` taller?

Comment: It would also be helpful if your example followed these guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Cheers. Just for future reference too, what did I not give in the original post?

Comment: If you don't want reinvent the wheel then you can try this -> [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

Comment: @discodowney - It wasn't that anything was missing, it was that the example was a little "noisy". Reducing examples to the most concise example that reproduces the issue makes it easier for you and others to debug.